# Reading an integer and / or character without an array

Tags: c

I need to read an integer one by one until i read a `'$'`, and then to determine the largest, smallest and so on. I could use a character variable and do it, but it works for numbers from 0 to 9. But how do I read integers of two or more digits **and at the same time, detect a `'$'`** - I used a `char *`, but  I guess it is equivalent to an array, which I should not use here. Also, char holds a single number / char, hence not suitable for larger numbers. What should I do?

Comment: C or C++ pick one, and if it is homework mark it as so.

Comment: from what will you read?

Comment: "I could use a character variable and do it, but it works for numbers from 0 to 9" What makes you think that?

Comment: @jrok The OP probably meant that using `char` you can only read one digit at a time.

Comment: @Joe: It is C, and it isn't a homework. I can use the same for numbers from 0-9, but not for the higher ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'scanf("%s")' to read a group of characters. You can then check if the first character is a '%' and terminate if so. Otherwise, call `atoi` to convert to an integer. Store the largest and smallest in integer types, not character types.

Basically, the only time you have to deal with characters is when you read them in and check if it's a '$'. Otherwise, use integers all the way through.

Comment: Have used atoi.... but in order to use %s, the declaration must be of the type: char varName[10];, isn't it?

Comment: No. It can just as well be `char *s; s=malloc(256);`.

Comment: Isn't the name of an array the same as a pointer to the first element in an array?

Comment: @user980411: It depends what you mean by `array`. Since the stack is an array of bytes, if you "can't use an array", you can't call any functions.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I should not call functions too.

Comment: @Poddlehat: No. The name of an array is an array, which decays into a pointer to its first element. The reverse is not true. If you have a pointer, there is no way to turn it into an array. Here we have just a pointer. (If you think they're the same, try passing both to `sizeof`. One will give you the size of the array, the other will give you the size of the pointer to its first element.)

Comment: @user980411: Then it is all but impossible. Without calling a function, how could you read any input?

Comment: @David Schwartz: By functions, I meant user defined ones; This is a program to sort, and you should not use functions to do the same... the standard ones fine...

Comment: @user980411: Then by "you may not use arrays" they must literally mean C arrays, as in 'char[]' or 'int[]'. If they mean arrays in the general sense of any multi-byte structure (which is implemented as an array of bytes), then you can't write C at all.

Comment: Why has this answer been accepted? It doesn't obey to the constraints of the question...

Comment: @Matteo Italia: If a `char *` is 'equivalent to an array` then so is an `int`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: nope, I don't seem to recall that an `int` can be indexed.

Comment: Still, IMHO this homework could aim at two things: maybe it doesn't want to restrict strings, but it's just to make the student calculate some values (max, min, mean, ...) without storing the elements in data structures; the other possibility is that it wants a program completely free of arrays, including strings; still, if you know the behavior of scanf, it's even easier to do so than using a temporary buffer+sscanf.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: That's because it's already indexed. A local integer is an index relative to the stack pointer. The stack is an array of bytes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: that's just an implementation detail, the Standard knows nothing about the stack pointer; *and*, an integer can (and often will) be allocated into a CPU register, so in this frequent case there's no index/pointer involved in any case.

Comment: A CPU register is just an index into the array of CPU registers. Since this is a C problem, I think it's reasonable to assume that `array` means a C array. Pointers are not C arrays.

Answer (score 2):

No arrays, no pointers, no tricky char-by-char read & convert. Just plain `scanf` and `getchar`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int newValue=0;        /* value being acquired */
    int max;               /* current maximum value */
    int min;               /* current minimum value */
    int firstAcquired=0;   /* boolean flag set to 1 after first acquisition */
    int ch;                /* used as temporary storage for the getchar() */
    for(;;)
    {
        /* scanf returns the number of successfully acquired fields; here if it
           returns 0 means that the value couldn't be acquired */
        if(scanf("%d",&newValue)==0)
        {
            /* scanf failed, but it's guaranteed it put the offending character
               back into the stream, from where we can get it */
            ch=getchar();
            if(ch=='$' || ch==EOF)
                break;
            else
            /* from here to the break it's just to handle invalid input and EOF
               gracefully; if you are not interested you can replace this stuff
               with a random curse to the user */
            {
                puts("Invalid input, retry.");
                /* Empty the buffer */
                while((ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch!=EOF)
                    ;
            }
            /* if it's EOF we exit */
            if(ch==EOF)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
        /* Everything went better than expected */
            if(!firstAcquired || newValue>max)
                max=newValue;
            if(!firstAcquired || newValue<min)
                min=newValue;
            firstAcquired=1;
        }
    }
    if(firstAcquired)
    {
        printf("The maximum value was %d\n", max);
        printf("The minimum value was %d\n", min);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of spoiling all the fun, showing off, outright overkill and darn tooting fun:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename V>
void show_statistics(const V& data)
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
    std::cout << "data:\t"<< format('{' << auto_ % ", " << '}', data) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "min:\t" << *std::min_element(data.begin(), data.end()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "max:\t" << *std::max_element(data.begin(), data.end()) << std::endl;

    auto sum = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
    std::cout << "sum:\t" << sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "avg:\t" << (1.0*sum) / data.size() << std::endl;
}

void dostats(const std::vector<int>& data) { show_statistics(data); }

int main()
{
    std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    auto f = boost::spirit::istream_iterator(std::cin);
    decltype(f) l;

    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, +(+qi::int_ > "$") [ dostats ], qi::space);

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining input unparsed: " << std::string(f,l) << std::endl;

    return ok? 0:255;
}
```

#### Demo:

Sample run:

```
sehe@natty:/tmp$ ./test2 <<< "1 2 3 4 5 $ 3 -9 0 0 0 $ 900 9000 $ unparsed trailing text"
data:   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
min:    1
max:    5
sum:    15
avg:    3
data:   {3, -9, 0, 0, 0}
min:    -9
max:    3
sum:    -6
avg:    -1.2
data:   {900, 9000}
min:    900
max:    9000
sum:    9900
avg:    4950
Remaining input unparsed: unparsed trailing text
```

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Thx; well, only after prodding. and, ah, who cares :). it is good exercise, and should be quite educational / entertaining to read if there is anyone with the same curiosities as myself

Answer (score 0):

You can read char by char in a loop, check values and so on...

```
int i = 0;
char c = 0;
int size = 10;
int currentIndex = 0;
int* integers = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
int counter = 0;
do
{
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c == ' ') // Match space, used a number separator
    {
        if (counter != 0 && i != 0)
        {
            if (currentIndex >= size)
            {
                size += 5;
                integers = realloc(integers, size);
            }
            integers[currentIndex] = i;
            currentIndex++;
        }
        counter = 0;
        i = 0;
    }
    else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        i = (i * counter * 10) + (c - '0');
        counter++;
    }
}
while(c != '$');
```

Don't forget to `free` integers in the end!

Comment: OP said it's C. (see question comments)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting what you want correctly it should be something like this:

```
int i = 0;
char c = getchar();
while (c != '$')
{
    i = i * 10 + (c - '0');
    c = getchar();
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: See question comments, it's C.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 16
#define DATA_MAX_SIZE 64

int main(){
    char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    int data[DATA_MAX_SIZE];
    int i,value,counter = 0;
    char *buffp,*p;
    while(NULL!=fgets(buff,BUFF_SIZE,stdin)){
        buff[BUFF_SIZE - 1]='\0';
        buffp = buff;
next:   while(isspace(*buffp))
            ++buffp;
        if(*buffp == '\0')
            continue;
        value = strtol(buffp, &p, 0);
        if(counter == DATA_MAX_SIZE){
            printf("over data max size!\n");
            break;
        } else if(p != buffp){
            data[counter++]=value;
            if(*p == '\0' || *p == '\r'|| *p == '\n')
                continue;
            buffp = p;
            goto next;
        } else {
            if(*p == '$')
                break;
            printf("format error\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    //check code 
    for(i=0;i<counter;++i){
        printf("data[%d]=%d\n",i, data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1 2 3
123
456
99 $
data[0]=1
data[1]=2
data[2]=3
data[3]=123
data[4]=456
data[5]=99

12345

4
$
data[0]=12345
data[1]=4
```